# My do-release-upgrade to 23.04 (from 22.10) failed and now apt lists many packages suitable for autoremove

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I recently performed a 'do-release-upgrade' from 22.10 to 23.04 on my Desktop installation.  It went well until this point:

```
2023-04-21 08:19:23,651 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic': 'installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1'
2023-04-21 08:19:23,652 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic: installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
2023-04-21 08:19:29,225 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'linux-headers-generic': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'
2023-04-21 08:19:29,225 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() linux-headers-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
2023-04-21 08:19:29,225 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against linux-headers-generic 
2023-04-21 08:20:05,416 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'linux-generic': 'dependency problems - leaving unconfigured'
2023-04-21 08:20:05,417 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() linux-generic: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
2023-04-21 08:20:05,417 DEBUG dpkg error because of dependency problems, not reporting against linux-generic 
2023-04-21 08:23:41,678 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic': 'installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1'
2023-04-21 08:23:41,678 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic: installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
2023-04-21 08:24:06,510 ERROR Exception during pm.DoInstall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-nbne_rgq/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 220, in run
    res = pm.do_install(self.writefd)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
2023-04-21 08:24:06,539 ERROR SystemError from cache.commit(): installArchives() failed
2023-04-21 08:24:06,539 ERROR found exception: 'E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'
2023-04-21 08:24:09,768 DEBUG Running PostInstallScript: './xorg_fix_proprietary.py'
2023-04-21 08:24:09,789 DEBUG Running PostInstallScript: '/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/upgrade_lts_contract.py'
```

The problem was some stale DKMS stuff left behind by DisplayLink. I was able to get through that, and get a clean 'apt install -f' and was left with a functioning system.

However, ever since then, when I perform any 'apt' operation, I am presented with a huge list of packages to be 'autoremoved':

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aapt abootimg androguard android-framework-res android-libaapt android-libandroidfw android-libart
  android-libbacktrace android-libbase android-libcutils android-liblog android-libnativebridge
  android-libnativeloader android-libutils android-libziparchive apksigcopier apksigner apktool
  binutils-multiarch bruteforce-luks ca-certificates-mono caca-utils cli-common coreboot-utils
  coreboot-utils-doc cramfsswap dctrl-tools default-jdk-headless device-tree-compiler dexdump dh-dkms
  diffoscope diffoscope-minimal enjarify fatcat flashrom fontforge-common fontforge-extras fonts-cantarell
  fonts-inconsolata fonttools fp-compiler-3.2.2 fp-units-rtl-3.2.2 fp-utils fp-utils-3.2.2 fpc-source-3.2.2
  freeglut3 gcc-12-base:i386 giflib-tools gir1.2-mutter-11 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-xmlb-2.0 gist gnumeric
  gnumeric-common gnumeric-doc hdf5-tools indicator-messages java-wrappers jsbeautifier junit ledit
  lib2geom1.1.0 libabsl20210324 libaec0 libantlr-java libantlr3-runtime-java libaopalliance-java
  libapache-pom-java libapksig-java libappimage0 libarchive-tools libatinject-jsr330-api-java libavif14
  libb2-1 libbpf0 libcdi-api-java libclang-cpp15 libcommons-cli-java libcommons-compress-java
  libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-text-java libcupsfilters1
  libdom4j-java libegl-dev liberror-prone-java libexporter-tiny-perl libflac8 libfontembed1 libfontforge4
  libfwupdplugin7 libgeronimo-annotation-1.3-spec-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libgit2-1.3
  libgl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglut-dev libglut3.12 libglvnd-core-dev
  libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libgoffice-0.10-10 libgoffice-0.10-10-common libgs9-common libgssdp-1.2-0
  libguava-java libguice-java libgupnp-1.2-1 libhdf5-103-1 libhdf5-hl-100 libicu4j-java libicu71
  libiniparser1 libintellij-annotations-java libjansi-java libjavaparser-java libjavascriptcoregtk-5.0-0
  libjaxen-java libjcommander-java libjdom1-java libjetbrains-annotations-java libjsr305-java libldap-2.5-0
  liblerc3 liblist-moreutils-perl liblist-moreutils-xs-perl libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common
  libmaven-archiver-java libmaven-file-management-java libmaven-jar-plugin-java libmaven-parent-java
  libmaven-resolver-java libmaven-shared-io-java libmaven-shared-utils-java libmaven3-core-java
  libmono-btls-interface4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-corlib4.5-dll libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
  libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
  libmono-system4.0-cil libmonoboehm-2.0-1 libmpdec3 libmutter-11-0 libopengl-dev libperl5.34 libpfm4
  libplacebo192 libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-interpolation-java libplexus-io-java
  libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils2-java libpoppler123 libprocyon-java libprotobuf-lite23
  libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28
  libqt5opengl5 libqt6core6 libqt6dbus6 libqt6gui6 libqt6network6 libqt6opengl6 libqt6openglwidgets6
  libqt6printsupport6 libqt6sql6 libqt6sql6-sqlite libqt6test6 libqt6widgets6 libqt6xml6 libre2-9
  libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsaxonhe-java libsisu-inject-java libsisu-plexus-java libslf4j-java libsmali-java
  libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni libspiro1 libstringtemplate-java libsz2 libtext-trim-perl libtiff5 libtiffxx5
  libts0 libubootenv-tool libubootenv0.1 libwagon-provider-api-java libwebkit2gtk-5.0-0 libwireshark15
  libwiretap12 libwsutil13 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 libxerces2-java
  libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxmlb-dev libxmlbeans-java libxmlunit-java
  libxom-java libxpp3-java libxt-dev libxz-java libyaml-snake-java libz3-4 libz3-dev llvm llvm-15
  llvm-15-dev llvm-15-linker-tools llvm-15-runtime llvm-15-tools llvm-runtime mono-4.0-gac mono-gac
  mono-runtime mono-runtime-common mono-runtime-sgen mono-utils mtd-utils netkit-telnet ocaml ocaml-base
  ocaml-compiler-libs ocaml-interp ocaml-man ocaml-nox oggvideotools openjdk-11-jdk-headless
  openjdk-17-jdk-headless perl-modules-5.34 pgpdump procyon-decompiler pxlib1 pyqt5-dev-tools
  pyqt6-dev-tools python3-asn1crypto python3-binwalk python3-botocore python3-charset-normalizer
  python3-defusedxml python3-editorconfig python3-jsbeautifier python3-jsondiff python3-libarchive-c
  python3-magic python3-networkx python3-opengl python3-oscrypto python3-pdfminer python3-progressbar
  python3-pycryptodome python3-pydot python3-pypdf python3-pypdf2 python3-pyperclip python3-pyqt5.qtopengl
  python3-pyqt6 python3-pyqt6.sip python3-pyqtgraph python3-pyxattr python3-rpm python3-rsa
  python3-s3transfer python3-tlsh python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal qt6-base-dev-tools
  qt6-gtk-platformtheme qt6-qpa-plugins qt6-translations-l10n qtbase5-dev-tools qtchooser ruby3.0 sng
  sqlite3 toilet toilet-fonts u-boot-tools wabt xmlbeans
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Since it's been asked in comments; No, I haven't removed my -desktop package:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "ubuntu-desktop"
ubuntu-desktop                      install
ubuntu-desktop-minimal              install
```

How do I get this cleared up?  I'd like to be able to actually use 'apt autoremove' without worrying that my system will be rendered useless.

Thanks in advance,
-nic

Comment: Have you explored where the package(s) come from?  ie. many look 3rd party and not from Ubuntu repositories (*but I could be wrong too*), I picked one (*at random*) I felt that was is found in Ubuntu repositories and `coreboot-utils` is version `4.15~dfsg-3` but it's not an installed package on my own system..  Most issues in *release-upgrade* are due to 3rd party packages, and those aren't essential to a Ubuntu system.  Also being specific as to if your installation is desktop & server is helpful...

Comment: My apologies; I only posted a small subset of the packages listed, due to the length.  I thought it would be better not to list them all.  I'll edit the question to include the full list, which is quite extensive. -nic

Comment: @karel, I do not believe this is due to unattended upgrades.  This only just appeared as a problem immediately following the interrupted do-release-upgrade.  In any event, unlike that poster, I do not have 'autoremove unused dependencies' feature active.

Comment: Looks like you might have removed your`____-desktop` metapackage

Comment: @user535733 No, I haven't removed any ____-desktop packages (see edit, above).

Comment: Then go ahead and autoremove all those webpage-development and secondary (non-default) applications and long-forgotten add-ons. If you autoremove something important, simply reinstall it. The alternative is to go through the list, item by item, and determine if you want it (were I in your shoes, that's what I would do).